# azure service accesible to only certain azure websites

Tags: azure

I have a bunch of REST services running in a VM in azure. I'd like to consume them from azure websites in a secure way. I.e. I don't want these services to be accessible from anywhere other than the azure websites.

Is it possible put this limitation? I know that I can limit access to the endpoints by providing IP address ranges but websites don't have fixed IP addresses.

thanks

Comment: This should be posted to ServerFault, not StackOverflow. That said: You can add your website to a vnet, which might help your scenario.

Answer (score 0):

If you set an unique IP can do it. But remember what the static IP are not available in all web hosting plans.